# How can I deploy web app on Tomcat from running app on weblogic

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic

I would like to develop updater app. Lets say I've got:
- Running weblogic 10.3.5
- Running Updater App on the weblogic 10.3.5
- Running old version of the app on the same weblogic 10.3.5

I would like to
- Stop old app
- Undeploy old app
- Deploy new version of app (lets assume that I've got new app war file somewere in Updater app resourcess.

Is it possible to do such remote deployment on weblogic 10.3.5 from another app at all?

Comment: Search for "deploying war programmatically in tomcat" or something similar. There are some answers out there like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498577/tomcat-remote-programmatic-deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing custom class loader for your application.By writing custom classloader , you can discard old classloader ,and create new one which will flush (enable for gc) , old classes and latest classes will be loaded from disk.